# Si existe la ñ, ¿por qué no la r̃ o la l̃?

Tags: historia, ortografía, abreviaturas

Sabemos que el origen de la letra *ñ* viene del grupo *nn*, ya que al duplicarse la letra n se cambiaba la pronunciación. Con el tiempo, y para economizar, los copistas comenzaron a representar el grupo *nn* con una única *n* y una tilde encima que indicaba la duplicidad. Sin embargo, la duplicación de la *l* y de la *r* también da lugar a sonidos diferentes, pero no se crearon las grafías *r̃* o *l̃* en nuestro idioma.

¿Alguien conoce el motivo de esta discriminación?

Comment: Bueno, para el dígrafo _ll_ existió la ele rota, una ligadura de dos eles: Ꝇ ꝇ, pero no estoy seguro si se usaron de manera significativa en textos castellanos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En manuscritos medievales, la tilde, o, más bien, la raya horizontal sobre la letra precedente, no indicaba la duplicación una letra, sino una `m` o `n` omitida¹. Por eso hoy se usa en varios idiomas, como el portugués, para indicar nasalización. Es uno de los pocos signos de abreviación medievales que sobreviven (aunque no con la función original).

¹ Nota: la línea horizontal y la tilde se usaban también como marcas de abreviación genéricas.

Que yo sepa, no había marcas de abreviación para letras dobles, o para `r` o `l`, y si las había, probablemente no serían muy usadas. El acusativo singular y el genitivo plural del latín (terminación en `-m` en casi todas las declinaciones) hacen a una abreviación de `m` algo muy útil y muy usado.

Un poco más de información: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation#Marks_with_independent_meaning

Agrego una traducción al inglés que encontré online del libro italiano en el que se basa parcialmente el artículo de Wikipedia: [*The elements of abbreviation in medieval Latin paleography*, de Adriano Capelli](https://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/bitstream/handle/1808/1821/47cappelli.pdf) (PDF).

Comment: Había muchas otras abreviaturas, pero la abreviatura para -um, etc, no era u con tilde sino algo que parece la z gótica o un 3 enterrado o bien un g/9 volante (y si era rum, era ꝝ).  La tilde podría indicar cualquier abreviatura (nr̃a was an abbreviation for *nuestra* and d̃ was extremely common for *de*), y en el texto que estoy editando ahora, la encuentro sobre la a, b, d, e, g, i, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, e y).

Comment: @guifa Supongo que dependerá del país, la época, el monje... [Acá](https://foundinantiquity.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/mtilde.jpg) hay unas úes con tilde.

Comment: Sí sí, claro. Pero estoy hablando de textos en castellano. La q con tilde por ejemplo sobrevive hasta el siglo XVII fácilmente (y hoy en la escritura, como c con tilde para con).

Comment: Bueno, pero en castellano no hay palabras que terminen en -um, ¿o sí? Agregué una nota sobre el uso de `~` para abreviaciones en general.

Comment: @guifa pero si en textos en español se podía encontrar la tilde con tanta frecuencia, incluyendo sobre la l y la r, y hoy en día prácticamente todas han desaparecido, la pregunta se puede mantener pero invirtiendo el sentido: ¿por qué la ñ fue la única que sobrevivió?